# Sims 3 and Windows 8

Tags: the-sims-3, windows-8

Sims 3 keeps dropping out at random locations on Windows 8. I utilized a Error Log reader to find that it is saying my graphics are out of date. My question is that Do I always have to declare where a file is located that I want in High Performance mode in my Switchable graphics panel? I recently migrated the install to another directory and I'm assuming it didnt make the jump with the file so the chipset is running the game and not the card.

OR

Is it just windows 8 and a newer build of the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running the Sims as administrator and play with compatibility mode (like putting it on windows 7 or XP). You can edit this by clicking on the application file (.exe) with the right mouse button. Then select properties and go to the compatibility tab.

Comment: I will try this out and report back later